# How to set up my windows azure account to support node js scripts?

Tags: c#, node.js, azure, iisnode

I have been able to run the node js scripts on my local emulator thanks to iisnode. But when i publish my project to windows azure, the node js scripts dont work. Do i have to set up something on my azure to get the node js scripts running, like installing iisnode or node js on azure? I was guessing they would be installed by default. I am pretty new to windows azure, please guide me on how i can run the node js scripts on my azure cloud platform.

EDIT:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/create-a-website-(mac)/

Above article says that the platform should have a working installation of Node.js and the Windows Azure SDK for Node.js, so i guess they are not installed by default on the azure?. Any idea on how i can check that? or even how i can install them? By RDP into my role instances or by some way through the azure management portal?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/create-a-website-(mac)/

Comment: It says that the platform should have a working installation of Node.js and the Windows Azure SDK for Node.js, so i guess they are not installed by default. Any idea on how i can check that? or even how i can install them? By RDP into my role instances or by some way through the azure management portal?

Comment: Are you creating a node.js based website or a cloud service?

Comment: Cloud service which has web role and worker role and its in .NET. I just have one node js script which i use for running socket.io

Comment: I see. I think your best bet would be to install all node.js related stuff (iisnode, node.js SDK for Azure) during role's start up as start up task. For pure node.js based deployments, please see this link: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/. You'll see an example for creating a pure node.js based cloud service using soket.io there.

Comment: Would it not work if i RDP into my web role instance and install those node js related stuff there?

Comment: Yes, it would certainly work however it is not recommended because if for some reason your role recycles (not reboots), your settings will be gone. Also you would need to do this on each and every instance of your role. So if you add an instance, you would need to make sure that you RDP into this new instance and install it manually there. With start up tasks, you're quite safe as each instance start up will ensure that necessary software are installed as soon as the role starts.

Comment: hmm that makes sense, but i would have to put those heavy installation files in my project, anyway i will give it a try! Thanks

Comment: Not necessarily. Take a look at Azure Bootstrapper project on CodePlex: http://bootstrap.codeplex.com/. Essentially you could put these files in blob storage and bootstrapper will handle it from there. HTH.

Comment: Btw just one doubt, the start up tasks will be started in the order i put them in my serviceDefinition.csdef right? because i have a start up task which runs my node js script but that should run after all these installations are finsihed

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but if you want the tasks to be started in order, then you would have to declare them as synchronous tasks. For more details on start up tasks, please see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180155.aspx